# Converting xlsx to csv Dates in wrong column

Tags: python, csv, xlsx

I'm trying to convert an xlsx file to csv. My pieced together code works, the only issue I'm running into is that when the date conversion happens they are placed in column 1 when the dates are in column 5. I'm at a loss as to what am I doing wrong? Any advice/examples?

```
def xlsx2csv ():
    wb = xlrd.open_workbook('.xlsx', '.csv' )
    sh = wb.sheet_by_index(0)

    file = open('.csv', 'wb')
    csv_out = unicodecsv.writer(, encoding = 'utf-8')

    for row_number in range(sh.nrows):
        date = sh.row_values(row_number)[5]

        if isinstance(date, float) or isinstance(date, int):
            year, month, day, hour, minute, sec = xlrd.xldate_as_tuple(date,0)
            py_date = "%2d/%2d/%04"% (month, day, year)
            wr.writerow[py_date] + sh.row_vlaues(row_number)[0:])
      else:
            wr.writerow([py_date] + sh_row_values(row_number)[0:])

     file.close()

xlsx2csv()
```

Answer (score 0):

You are appending the whole row to the date. 
This is how operator `+` is working with lists.

```
a = 1
b = [2,3,4]
a + b #[1,2,3,4]
```

Rework this code.

```
 wr.writerow[py_date] + sh.row_vlaues(row_number)[0:])
```

To something like.

```
new_row = sh.row_vlaues(row_number)[0:]
new_row[5] = py_date
wr.wroterow(new_row)  # save it to csv
```

Since the date is the 6th element in the array judging by `sh.row_values(row_number)[5]`

Comment: Thank you for the response. I'm having an issue though. My [py_code] call is no longer working. I'm getting an "invalid syntax". Any advice? Thanks.

Comment: I'm imagining that you have an error with the way you are calling your code.
`py_data` is a string.
`[py_date]` will create a list with  one element 'py_data'.